# Template Literal : no html output

Tags: template-literals

```
const name = 'Mazhar';
const age = 31;
const job = 'Web Developer';
const city = 'Mumbai';

let html;

html = '
<ul>
    <li>Name: ${name}</li>
    <li>Age: ${age}</li>
    <li>Job: ${job}</li>
    <li>City: ${city}</li>    
</ul>
';

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Hi my this code is not working. I have put it in .js file and linked it to my html file and checking in the console.

Thank You

Comment: In what way is it not working? Be specific.

Comment: post the error here.

Comment: Its not giving any output on html page 

Console says : custom.js:18 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mazharkhan/z77z4jh7/

Answer (score 0):

okay  So i had to add this line : 
on the body of my html page. I had added it in under   section